# Using NSXMLParser To Parse a Core Data Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsxmlparser

My XML file resembles to the following one:

```
<title>some text
<Dog>founded characters to parse</Dog>
</title>
```

I've used the function:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

to recognize the tags, but I want to send the text between the tags to my `NSManagedObject`
for example:

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    [currentTitle setTitle:???????????];
}
```

I know there is the function:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

But I'm not sure how to use it for the right Object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Introduction to Event-Driven XML Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html), it will answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is invalid so I'll give you an example with something a little more like this:

```
<title>
    <Text>some text</Text>
    <Dog>founded characters to parse</Dog>
</title>
```

You need to implement three delegate methods and you'll want to create a variable to hold the text as it is discovered:

### Header

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentValue;
```

### Implementation

```
- (id) init 
{    
    if( (self = [super init]) ) 
    {
        NSMutableString *value = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:500];
        self.currentValue = value;
        [value release];   
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                                         namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                                        qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
                                           attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{    
    [self.currentValue setString:@""]; // Clear your string at the start of each tag   
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{    
    [self.propertyValue appendString:string]; // append characters, this can be called multiple times
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                                       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                                      qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{    
    NSString *value = [self.propertyValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"dog"] ) {
        dog.someProperty = value;
        return;
    }   

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"text"] ) {
        currentTitle.title = value;
        return;
    }
}
```

So you need to implement didStart, foundCharacters, and didEnd.  On didStart is where you handle creating any value objects based on which tag you find.  Found characters is generally always implemented the same, you just append them... you can also apply any formatting if you like.  Did end is where you save your value objects and free up any resources.  I hope this helps you, it's all part of the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string` is the key.  Essentially you'll be managing an NSMutableString variable which will be stuffed with the values.  Then, in the `-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName` you'll be setting your properties with the value.

Here's a [more detailed look](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) on this process.